# Unity Camera flicker when going from 359 rotation to 0

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I'm using this simple CameraFollow script to have my camera follow behind my player's movements.  The problem is that my player can spin a full 360 degrees, and the camera has to rotate with it.  This works well, except when completing a full turn. When the player transform goes from 359 degrees back to 0, the camera flickers as it does a full backwards 360 degree loop to catch up, instead of moving 1 degree to catch up.  How can I fix this? 
In the code below the 'target' is my player, and 'trans' is the transform of the camera.  It's also worth noting that if the player stops at exactly 0 degrees it jumps back to 180 for some reason.

```
 public class CameraFollow : MonoBehaviour {

   [SerializeField] Transform target;
   [SerializeField] Vector3 defaultDistance = new Vector3(0f, 3.5f, -12f);
   [SerializeField] float distanceDamp = 0.05f;
   [SerializeField] Vector3 velocity = Vector3.one;

   Transform trans;

   private void Awake()
   {
       trans = transform;
   }

   private void FixedUpdate()
   {
       Vector3 toPos = target.position + (target.rotation * defaultDistance);
       Vector3 curPos = Vector3.SmoothDamp(trans.position, toPos, ref velocity, distanceDamp);
       trans.position = curPos;
       trans.up = target.up;
   }
}
```

Comment: Your code only shows the position update, not the rotation update.

Comment: The rotation is updated in the last line, by setting the camera transform.up to be the same as the players.

Comment: You probably shouldn't use FixedUpdate for this.

Comment: If I use Update or LateUpdate then I get very jittery movement from my player.

Comment: I believe it doesn't have anything to do with FixedUpdate.  I believe I need to use Quaternions somehow to allow the rotation of the camera to exceed 360 and just continue spinning.  This would replace the last line of the method, but I'm not sure how to properly use Quaternion.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my issue by changing the last line from 
`trans.up = target.up;`
to 
`trans.rotation = target.rotation;`